# Multiple SQL query with array

Tags: sql

So right now I have a `foreach`loop to do this, but I want to see if it could be done faster, by making one call to my sql. I have a sql query as this:

```
SELECT
    status.StatusName
    ,count(StatusName) AS Count
    ,TestRunsId
    ,testsuiteid
    ,testsuitecollectionid 

FROM testresults 
LEFT JOIN status on status.id = testresults.StatusId 
WHERE
    true
    AND testresults.testrunsid in ('3754', '3753', '3746')
    AND testresults.testsuiteid = '38'
    AND testresults.testsuitecollectionid = '17' 
GROUP BY
    TestRunsID
;
```

The thing is, `testsuiteid` and `testsuitecollectionid`, changes after every `testrunsid` has been checked. Here I'm wondering if it could be possible to make one sql query that checks every `testrunsid`, and then moves on to the next `testsuiteid` & `testsuitecollectionid` and then they would also be written as an array like  `testrunsid`.

```
SELECT
    status.StatusName
    ,count(StatusName) AS Count
    ,TestRunsId
    ,testsuiteid
    ,testsuitecollectionid 

FROM testresults 
LEFT JOIN status on status.id = testresults.StatusId 
WHERE
    true
    AND testresults.testrunsid in ('3754', '3753', '3746')
    AND testresults.testsuiteid in ('38', '39')
    AND testresults.testsuitecollectionid = ('17', '13')
GROUP BY
    TestRunsID
;
```

**How I think it should work**:

Check every `testrunsid` --> with `testsuiteid = 38` and `testsuitecollectionid = 17`, then moves on to `testsuiteid = 39` and `testsuitecollectionid = 13`where it checks every `testrunsid`.

Is it possible or should I just forget it, and keep my `foreach loop` with multiple SQL calls?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and only a few databases actually support proper arrays (e.g. Postgres). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why are you storing (or at least comparing) numbers as strings? `'17'` is a string `17` is a number

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean, but... can't you just omit the ``testsuiteid`` condition?
Aside from this: put the appropriate tag for the sql dialect you're using, as it may attract the right people. Also, tag the language you're using for your business logic and if possible add it, as it could help better understanding what you're trying to obtain as an output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT s.StatusName, count(s.StatusName) AS Count,
       tr.TestRunsId, tr.testsuiteid, tr.testsuitecollectionid 
FROM testresults tr LEFT JOIN
     status s
     ON s.id = tr.StatusId 
WHERE tr.testrunsid in (3754, 3753, 3746) AND
      tr.testsuiteid in (38, 39) AND
      tr.testsuitecollectionid = (17, 13)
GROUP BY s.statusName, tr.TestRunsId, tr.testsuiteid;
ORDER BY tr.testsuitecollectionid, tr.testsuiteid, tr.testrunsid;
```

Notes:

- The `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` columns should be consistent.
- Qualify *all* column names, especially in a query that has multiple tables.  I am assuming the columns come from `testresults`.
- Use table aliases to simplify writing and reading the query.
- I am assuming that the ids are all numbers, so I removed the single quotes.  If they are really strings, put the single quotes back in.
- I am not 100% sure I have the `ORDER BY` columns in the right order because I don't fully understand your description.